# Mediatr default handler and specific handlers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, architecture, mediatr

Let's say I have multiple customers using the same web api, some have specific business logic for the same routes, but most of them can be handled more generically.

I could create customer specific projects which would contain their own handler definitions. Then, I could load the appropriate assembly in the startup.cs of the web api. Since mediatr prioritize handlers in the executing assembly (the api), I could put the generic handlers there. In that case however, I won't be able to select the customer specific handler in the external assembly.

The workaround I have now is to move the customer specifics into a service layer, but since the product is ill-defined to say the least, it would be a wrong an unnecessary abstraction. I would prefer to have a bit more logic in the handlers until the understanding of the product gets better.

The situation is a bit of a mess, I am looking forward to suggestions, using the handlers might be the wrong idea here.

Comment: You could register your handlers as Keyed. Here's an example of how to do it: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/335#issuecomment-439729821

Comment: That would require to use unity or autofac since I am using the default .net core DI. Also, it seems I would need to manually specify keys for each handler and with dozens of handlers I don't think it would be maintainable.

I could use the DI to register the handlers with some custom logic in the startup, however when you use services.AddMediatR(assembly), it maps every handler in the assembly by default. I might be missing something on how the DI and mediatr work together.

Comment: I don't know about maintainability but in this setup you'll always need some kind of configuration - even if you only keep track of the specific ones - to select the right set of handlers for each customer, the key is just a way to make the selection process work through DI.